# Decoding Nested JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Excuse me if this has been covered, but I've looked and can't find an answer that works.

I have the following JSON (shortened for clarity):

```
[{
    "header": {
        "msg_type": "0001"
    },
    "body": {
        "event_type": "ARRIVAL",
        "train_id": "384T22MJ20"
    }
},{
    "header": {
        "msg_type": "0003"
    },
    "body": {
        "event_type": "DEPARTURE",
        "train_id": "382W22MJ19"
    }
}]
```

Now I know I can use json_decode to create a php array, but not knowing much about php I don't know how to get it to do what I want. I need to be able to access a value from each array. For example I would need to extract the train_id from each array. At the moment I have this:

```
$file = "sampleData.json";
$source = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($source);

$msgbdy = $data->body;
foreach($msgbdy as $body){
   $trainID = $body->train_id;
}
```

I know this is wrong, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks everyone, used a combination of the answers to achieve what I needed. Can't vote things up yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to pass it `true` as a parameter, it is easier to work with associative arrays than objects:

```
$messages = json_decode($source, true);
foreach($messages as $message){
   $trainID = $message["body"]["train_id"];
}
```

Comment: @specializt and meda always use isset or empty. I like the use of json_decode to array.

Answer (score 2):

anonymous objects are deserialized as array-members, `foreach` can handle that :

```
$objs = json_decode($source)
foreach($objs as $obj)
{
   $body = $obj->body; //this is another object!
   $header = $obj->header; //yet another object!
}
```

and within that loop, you can now access `msg_type`, `train_id` and `event_type` via `$body` and `$header`

Answer (score 0):

You process it in the wrong order: your string is an *array* of objects. Not an object with arrays.

You first need the large foreach loop to iterate over the array and then access for each element the "body" and "train_id".

Your code should thus read:

```
foreach($data as $item) {
    echo $item->body->train_id; //or do something else with $item->body->train_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
$data = json_decode($source);

foreach ($data as $message) {
    $trainId = $message->body->train_id;
    // Not sure what you want to do wit this ^
}
```

You need to loop over each whole entry. See how where the data is repeated, and that is what you need to loop over.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to access an array like an object. The array notation would be `$data[0]['body']` to retrieve the value for the "body" key in the first entry in the array.